# Netty and Ktor throwing jetty.io.EofException

Tags: jetty, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I am creating an application with Ktor and using Jetty. There is a rule, that, before taking a certain action, I need to check if the endpoint is up / down.
For this I created a function that I check according to the service.

```
suspend fun checkStatus(
  target: Target,
  login: String,
  passwordLogin: String,
  url: String
) {
  when (target) {
    Target.Elasticsearch -> {
      val client = HttpClient(Jetty) {
        install(Auth) {
          basic {
            username = login
            password = passwordLogin
          }
        }
      }
      runCatching {
        client.get<String>(url)
      }.onFailure {
        it.printStackTrace()
        throw it
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To decrease the size of the function I just used the example with elasticsearch. So I have a function that checks if the elasticsearch is up / down

```
suspend fun checkElasticStatus(
  username: String,
  password: String,
  https: Boolean,
  host: String,
  port: String
) = checkStatus(
  target = Target.Elasticsearch,
  login = username,
  passwordLogin = password,
  url = if (https) "https://$host:$port" else "http://$host:$port"
)
```

So I use this function in the Controller, before continuing with certain logic.

```
fun Route.orchestration() {
  route("/test") {
    post {
      runCatching {
        checkElasticStatus(
          environmentVariable(ev, "elk.username"),
          environmentVariable(ev, "elk.password"),
          environmentVariable(ev, "elk.https").toBoolean(),
          environmentVariable(ev, "elk.host"),
          environmentVariable(ev, "elk.port")
        )

        /** other codes **/
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

But I'm always getting the error:

> org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:283)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Flusher.process(HTTP2Flusher.java:259)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.newStream(HTTP2Session.java:543)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$jettyRequest$1.invoke(JettyHttpRequest.kt:40)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$jettyRequest$1.invoke(JettyHttpRequest.kt)
> at io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.UtilsKt.withPromise(utils.kt:14)     at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt.executeRequest(JettyHttpRequest.kt:39)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$1.invokeSuspend(JettyHttpRequest.kt)
> at
> kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
>
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException   at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:501)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:263)
> ... 18 more
>
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:283)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Flusher.process(HTTP2Flusher.java:259)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.newStream(HTTP2Session.java:543)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$jettyRequest$1.invoke(JettyHttpRequest.kt:40)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$jettyRequest$1.invoke(JettyHttpRequest.kt)
> at io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.UtilsKt.withPromise(utils.kt:14)     at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt.executeRequest(JettyHttpRequest.kt:39)
> at
> io.ktor.client.engine.jetty.JettyHttpRequestKt$executeRequest$1.invokeSuspend(JettyHttpRequest.kt)
> at
> kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
>
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException   at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:501)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:263)
> ... 18 more

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jetty` engine supports HTTP/2 protocol only.

`org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException` is thrown when I make a request to resource which can only respond with HTTP/1.1, e.g. http://www.google.com.

However, the error is misleading and there is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-874) in bugtracker about it.